# Formatting radgrid exporting to PDF

Tags: pdf, radgrid, export-to-pdf

I have a datatable dt, and want to make a PDF file from it. Everything is dynamic and it works but I can't format the layout such as alternate row background etc. Here is my code :

```
   private void MakeGridExportToPDF(string strTitle, DataTable dt)
{
    using (RadGrid grid = new RadGrid { AutoGenerateColumns = false, ShowHeader = true, })
    {
        grid.NeedDataSource += (object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e) =>
              {
                  grid.DataSource = dt;
              };
        // Add columns
        dt.Columns.OfType<DataColumn>().ToList().ForEach(col =>
        {
            grid.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(new GridBoundColumn { DataField = col.ColumnName, HeaderText = col.Caption.ToCamel() });
        });
        GridExportSettings export = grid.ExportSettings;
        export.OpenInNewWindow = true;
        export.FileName = strTitle;
        export.IgnorePaging = true;
        GridPdfSettings pdf = export.Pdf;
        pdf.PageHeight = Unit.Parse("210mm"); // 
        pdf.PageWidth = Unit.Parse(GetPageWidth(grid.MasterTableView.Columns.Count)); // 
        pdf.DefaultFontFamily = "Arial Unicode MS";
        pdf.PageTopMargin = Unit.Parse("45mm");
        grid.ItemCreated += (object sender, GridItemEventArgs e) =>
         {
             GridItem item = e.Item;
             if (item is GridDataItem)
             {
                 item.Style["vertical-align"] = "middle";
                 item.Style["text-align"] = "center";
             }
             switch (item.ItemType) //Mimic RadGrid appearance for the exported PDF file
             {
                 case GridItemType.Item:
                     item.Style["background-color"] = "#DFDFDF";
                     item.Font.Italic = true;
                     break;
                 case GridItemType.AlternatingItem:
                     item.Style["background-color"] = "#FFFFFF";

                     break;
                 case GridItemType.Header:
                     item.Style["background-color"] = "#FFFFFF";
                     item.Style["Color"] = "#767676";
                     item.Font.Bold = true;
                     break;
                 case GridItemType.Footer:
                     item.Style["background-color"] = "#FFFFFF";


                     break;
             }
         };

        this.smCSVFile.Controls.Add(grid);
        grid.MasterTableView.ExportToPdf();
        bDone = true;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong. the ItemCreated is triggered when grid is created first but not when is exported and don't see any changes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: My problem has been resolved by removing use(RadGrid grid ....

Answer (score 0):

My problem has been resolved by removing use(RadGrid grid .... and just make the `Radgrid = new RadGrid { AutoGenerateColumns = false, ShowHeader = true, }`